# How do you pass a List object to Javascript in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight class with the following block of code:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
            s = command.DDECommand; //command is an object that i pass to this static class and DDECommand is a List<string> within that object.
            if (HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.Name == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
            {
                (Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("javascript_cmd", s);
                });
                return true;
            }
```

I've read [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/32131/184880.aspx) that you should be able to pass a List of strings to a javascript function and be able to iterate through the list in javascript. However when I try to do the this, as illustrated in the above code, I find that javascript only receives the parameter as the string `"{...}"`. Was [this post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/32131/184880.aspx) incorrect? Is there anything I am doing wrong in passing the List?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this:

One thing to remember, when returning objects from a Silverlight method call to JavaScript, is they need to be marked as Scriptble using the **ScriptableType attribute**

[This article here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/06/Silverlight-and-JavaScript-Interop-Basics.aspx) should help